# Meteor Display Tasks Only Assigned to Current User

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I know how to display or publish items that were only created by a specific user, but In my application managers assign items to specific users. Then the users log in and go to their dashboard. I would like for the users to ONLY see items assigned to them.

I am currently using AutoForm to create the tasks. I have the users first and last name printing out just fine, but when it comes to the next step of somehow assigning their userId to the item, and then when they go to their dashboard validating against that I am a little stuck.

Here is my current schema. The inspector is the user.

```js
 inspector: {
   type: String,
   label: "Inspector",
   autoform: {
     afFieldInput: {
       type: "select2",
       firstOption: 'Choose an Inspector',
       options: function() {
         return Meteor.users.find({}, {
           sort: {
             profile: 1,
             firstName: 1
           }
         }).map(function(c) {
           return {
             label: c.profile.firstName + " " + c.profile.lastName,
             value: c.profile.firstName + " " + c.profile.lastName
           };
         });
       }
     }
   }
 },
```

I should also mention that I think I need to publish ALL tasks to the page; because there are roles. I need admins and Managers to be able to see all tasks, but "inspectors" to only see their own specific tasks assigned to only their user ID.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, Admin and managers can assign tasks to inspectors. Inspectors can also assign tasks to themselves. And what the inspector should see is his own tasks which includes what was assigned by himself and admin/managers to him?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply! You are nearly correct. So basically the admins and managers are adding client locations. Then the inspectors add tasks for the location they are inspecting, and a pass/fail for each item. 

All of that is working fine. The only thing I am lacking is giving the manager the ability to assign different locations to each inspectors. I would like the inspectors first/last name to display on the location, but at the same hand want to be able to use the userId to allow the inspector to ONLY see their locations.